# Define different routes for different programs on Windows

Tags: windows, networking, routing

Is it possible, under Windows, to define different routes for different programs? In other words: if I had 2 programs running on the same machine, can I force program A to use a gateway and program B a different one? Assuming both gateways are on the same network and through the same network adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do this if the application itself can bind to a specific network adapter.  Things like PWS (Personal Web Server) for instance can in some cases do this.  But generally the answer would be no.

A more direct question would be why you have two gateways on the same network.  Odds are there is probably an easier way to do load balancing or "routing" on a network appliance.

Comment: Well, my scenario is almost this: we've got two ways to reach the internet one is via a DSL ISP, the other one via a wireless ISP. The first one (DSL) has less bandwith but better latency so I'd like to normally use wireless link for everyday task while still use the DLS for VOIP applications.

Comment: THere are some products on the market that offer dual WAN interfaces.  I basically have a similar setup in my office with 100Mbps Fiber as my primary and a 10Mbps fixed wireless as the backup.  We use Sonicwall E5500 (medium/higher end in terms of performance).  But the lower end units can do dual WAN too.  One thing that is nice is that in the routing you can specify traffic on a port/machine basis can use one connection over another.  The other benefit is that when one goes down, the users just keep working as it knows the circuit is down and uses the backup instead.

Comment: Definitively this is a valid option even if this presuppose some little modifications to my actual network topology, but the advantages will payback. Thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome and good luck..